# How to download email attachments with pop3 protocol using java sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, email, email-attachments, pop3

I connected to my gmail account through java sockets and retrieved all my emails using pop3 commands. And now I want to download all attachments to specific catalog in my computer using sockets. I do not want to use java mail package.

Any examples, ideas would help.

Comment: Attachments are stored in the email body, so if you've downloaded the entire body you've got them. Google for "mime multipart" to learn how to decode them.

Comment: I cant find any example of minemultipart with sockets but only with java mail. As I already mentioned I am trying not use java mail package.

Comment: You will have to parse the MIME data yourself (or use a 3rd party parser). Read RFCs [2045](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045), [2046](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046), and [2047](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2047), they define the MIME format and processing rules you will need to handle.  Email parsing is outside the scope of POP3, it only provides you with the raw unprocessed data.

Comment: Since you are dealing with Gmail, you might consider using IMAP instead of POP3. IMAP is more complex than POP3, but it gives you much more structured access to mailboxes and emails, even pieces of an email such as individual attachments.